# Arcgis crashes with Bing Maps

Tags: arcgis-desktop, bing-maps, arcgis-10.4

I'm using ArcGis 10.4 and it crashes when I pan Bing Maps.
Zooming in and out is working. Esri Imagery works as well.

Does anyone have experience with that and know what is the problem?

Comment: I'm having similar issues.  Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: It seems to me that ArcGis crashes when the internet speed or network connection is to slow and the tiles can't load fast enough. When I'am alone in the office, it works fine. Strangely with ArcGIS 10.3 on a Mac at the same office there are never problems.